# Numerical simulations of n-competing species

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

I would like to make numerical simulations of n-species sharing the common resource in Matlab. My system is of the form;

```
dx_n/dt=x_n(2 - x_{n-1} - x_n),

dx_{n-1}/dt=x_{n-1}(3 - x_{n-2} - x_{n-1} - x_n).
```

I have written a code for "n=5" as follows;

```
dx = @(t,x) [
  x(1); x(1)*(2-x(1)-x(2));
  x(2); x(2)*(3-x(2)-x(2)-x(3));
  x(3); x(3)*(3-x(2)-x(3)-x(4));
  x(4); x(4)*(3-x(3)-x(4)-x(5));
  x(5); x(5)*(2-x(4)-x(5))];
tspan=[0 15];
x0=[0 2 0 3 0 4 0 6 0 8]
[t,x]=ode45(@(t,x) dx(t,x), tspan, x0);
figure(1)
plot(t,x)
```

My question is, "Is there an easier way in which I can write a general code for any 'n'?". Can someone please help me. I'm new to Matlab.

Comment: Your differential equation in the formula (and comment to the answer) has a first order derivative on the left side, your code however has a form that implies that there should be a second order derivative. Please decide on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Well, thanks for that observation. I want to solve the first order derivative. Thanks!

Comment: Could you test my one-line ODE function?

Comment: Thanks, LutL. I have been trying running your code. However, I still receive errors. I can't figure out how these errors come about. I'm still trying out though. Thanks once more.

Comment: I added some code that works in octave, replacing the solver `lsode` with `ode45` and adapting the return values it should also work in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Seems very tricky, if not impossible, to code the differential in an *anonymous function* as you did for `n=5`.

So you have to put the math into an explicit (not anonymous) function

```
function dx = spdiff(t,x)
n = len(x);
dx(1) = x(1);
dx(2) = x(1) .* (2 - x(1) - x(2));
for k = 2:(n-1)
    dx(2*k-1) = x(k);
    dx(2*k)   = x(k) .* (3 - x(k-1) - x(k) - x(k+1));
end
dx(2*n-1) = x(n);
dx(2*n)   = x(n) .* (2 - x(n-1) - x(n));
```

And then to solve it

```
[t,x]=ode45(@spdiff, tspan, x0);
```

Addressing the comment...
Let's use the set of ODE in original question, I have written out the complete code above.

Comment: Thanks Doctor Core. However, I am kind of confused how I can couple the functions into the `code` suppose we have specific a system, say, dx1/dt=x1(2-x1-x2) and dx2/dt=x2(3-x1-x2-x3). Thanks in advance!

Comment: When trying to write it all out for you (maybe I shouldn't do that), I figured out you might have made some typo in your original question, please consider to edit it.

Comment: Thanks Doctor Core for your code. Let me try finishing it up. I am sure the problem will be solved. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 0):

To get the derivative of the original system in one line use

```
dx = @(t,x) x.*conv(1-x, [1 1 1], 'same')
```

`1-x` produces the vector with entries `1-x(k)`, [`conv`olution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) with `[1 1 1]` produces the array

```
[ 1-x(1), 2-x(1)-x(2),  3-x(1)-x(2)-x(3), 3-x(2)-x(3)-x(4),... 
                       ..., 3-x(n-2)-x(n-1)-x(n), 2-x(n-1)-x(n), 1-x(n)]
```

The option `shape='same'` reduces that to the central part, that is, cuts away the first and last element. Then with elementwise multiplication you get exactly the right side of the formula.

One integration with the initial values from the question divided by 10 looks like

[image]

In `gnu-octave`, which is similar to matlab, the following code produces a similar graph

```
dx = @(x,t) x.*conv(1-x, [1 1 1], 'same')

tspan = 0:0.1:10;    
x0=[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8];
sol = lsode(dx, x0, tspan );
plot(tspan, sol)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The code really works well in Octave. Thanks for your time